# Rsnapshot: folder ownership permissions to 'backups' group instead of root

Tags: linux, permissions, ownership, rsnapshot

I am using rsnapshot to make daily backups of a MYSQL database on a server. Everything works perfectly except the ownership of the directory is `root:root`. I would like it to be `root:backups` to enable me to easily download these backups to a local computer over an ssh connection. (My ssh user has sudo permissions but I don't want to have to type in the password every time I make a local copy of the backups. This user is part of the *backups* group.)

In `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` I have this line:

`backup_script   /usr/local/bin/backup_mysql.sh  mysql/`

And in the file `/usr/local/bin/backup_mysql.sh` I have:

```
umask 0077
# backup the database
date=`date +"%y%m%d-%h%m%s"`                                                                                             
destination=$date'-data.sql.gz'
/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/root/.my.cnf --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --routines data | gzip -c > $destination
/bin/chmod 660 $destination
/bin/chown root:backups $destination
```

The file structure that results is:

```
/backups/
├── [drwxrwx---]  daily.0
│   └── [drwxrwx---]  mysql [error opening dir]
├── [drwxrwx---]  daily.1
│   └── [drwxrwx---]  mysql [error opening dir]
```

The ownership of the backup data file itself is correct, as `root:backups`, but I cannot access that file because the folder it is in, `mysql`, belongs to `root:root`.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more chgrp commands to a `cmd_postexec` command.

Comment: Looks like a `umask` issue. Try setting it to `umask 002` just before you call `rsnapshot`

Comment: I've tried setting the umask to 002. We'll see tomorrow what effect this had!

Comment: @roaima When i run `umask` in bash it returns `0002`. I tried `umask 002` in the backup script which didn't help, and nor did commenting out that line completely. The permissions on the mysql folder are still `drwxrwx---`

Comment: Did you set it before calling `rsnapshot`, or only in your MySQL backup snippet? It must be before `rsnapshot`

Comment: @roaima I had only set it in the MySQL backup snippet. I just made a script which will be fired from `cmd_preexec` in /etc/rsnapshot.conf. The script has one line, `umask 002`. I'll see tomorrow whether that worked or not!

Comment: No... It won't work there. Please set the umask _before you run `rsnapshot`_.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand how to do that. `rsnapshot` is run automatically by cron. How would I run that command before rsnapshot is run?

Comment: Change the cron line to have `umask 002; rsnapshot...` instead of just `rsnapshot...`. Don't change the five numbers at the beginning of the line as they define when the job gets run.

Comment: I've updated /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot to have lines looking like this: `0 12    * * *           root    umask 002; /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily` However the permissions on the `mysql` directory being created each day are still 770.

Comment: @meuh `cmd_postexec` allows me to run `chown -R root:backups /backups/` which works. Shall I write that as the answer to this question or would you prefer to do it yourself?

Comment: Done. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default `/etc/rsnapshot` configuration file is the following:

```
# Specify the path to a script (and any optional arguments) to run right
# after rsnapshot syncs files
# cmd_postexec   /path/to/postexec/script
```

You can use `cmd_postexec` to run a `chgrp` command on the resulting files which need their group ownership changing.